# Bulk Insert in sql-server while updating multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I have one table that has fields like

```
ID   ProductID  CategoryID and lot of columns......

1    1          1
2    1          2
3    2          1
4    2          2
5    2          3
```

I want to insert all the records in this table to two separate tables that have a structure like

```
ID    ProductID   (Skip CategoryID column)....
1      1
2      2
```

And

```
ID  ProductID  CategoryID

1    1          1
2    1          1
3    2          2
4    2          2
5    2          2
```

I can easily do this using code but i want to use pure SQL.

Normally i can insert it like

```
Insert into Table1 select * from Table2
```

But in this case after for every row there are multiple insert.

Any idea in this regard is appreciable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, your issue is that when you select from the first table into the second table you are getting multiple rows for each product. To get round this you can do something like :

```
INSERT INTO TABLE2 
SELECT DISTINCT 
    ProductID
    , etc. etc. -- Other columns as required
FROM
    TABLE1
```

and then to inset into the third table would just require:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE3
SELECT DISTINCT 
    ProductID
    , CategoryID
FROM
    TABLE1
```

Comment: Absolutely correct, i dont know why this does not stuck into my mind, and i asked stupid question. Thanks for the help. You save my time i am about to write a code in c#